# ensuring that a mesos task is not running after a TASK_LOST status update

Tags: mesos

I am trying to write a simple Mesos framework that can relaunch tasks that don't succeed.

The basic algorithm, which seems to be mostly working, is to read in a task list (e.g. shell commands) and then launch executors, waiting to hear back status messages. If I get `TASK_FINISHED`, that particular task is done. If I get `TASK_FAILED/TASK_KILLED`, I can retry the task elsewhere (or maybe give up).

The case I'm not sure about is `TASK_LOST` (or even slave lost). I am hoping to ensure that I don't launch another copy of a task that is already running.  After getting `TASK_LOST`, Is it possible that the executor is still running somewhere, but a network problem has disconnected the slave from the master? Does Mesos deal with this case somehow, perhaps by having the executor kill itself (and the task) when it is unable to contact the master?

More generally, how can I make sure I don't have two of the same task running in this context?

Answer (score 4):

Let me provide some background first and then try to answer your question.

1) The difference between `TASK_LOST` and other terminal unsuccessful states is that restarting a lost task could end in `TASK_FINISHED`, while failed or killed will most probably not.

2) Until you get a `TASK_LOST` you should assume your task is running. Imagine a Mesos Agent (Slave) dies for a while, but the tasks may still be running and will be successfully reconciled, even though the connection is temporarily lost.

3) Now to your original question. The problem is that it is utterly hard to have exactly once instance running (see e.g. [1] and [2]). If you have lost connection to your task, that can mean either a (temporary) network partition or that your task has died. You basically have to choose between two alternatives: either having the possibility of multiple instances running at the same time, or possibly having periods when there are no instances running.

4) It's not easy to guarantee that two tasks are not running concurrently. When you get a `TASK_LOST` update from Mesos it means either your task is dead or orphaned (it will be killed once reconciled). Now imagine a situation when a slave with your task is disconnected from the Mesos Master (due to a network partition): while you will get a `TASK_LOST` update and the Master ensures the task is killed once the connection is restored, your task will be running on the disconnected slave until then, which violates the guarantee given you have already started another instance once you got the `TASK_LOST` update.

5) Things you may want to look at:

- `recovery_timeout` on Mesos slaves regulates when tasks commit suicide if the `mesos-slave` process dies
- `slave_reregister_timeout` on the Mesos Master specifies how much time do slaves have to reregister with the Mesos Master and have their tasks reconciled (basically, when you get `TASK_LOST` updates for unreachable tasks).

[1] http://antirez.com/news/78

[2] http://bravenewgeek.com/you-cannot-have-exactly-once-delivery/

Comment: Thanks very much for the response. In my case, I'm actually fine with "possibly having periods when there are no instances running". I essentially just have a list of shell commands that each need to succeed. The guarantees I need are a) two of them are not running concurrently, and b) once the master gets a TASK_FINISHED, that task will never run again. Is it possible?

Comment: Just run one instance of your task (shell command) and do not restart it unless you get a terminal status update. When you get a `TASK_LOST` from Mesos it means either your task is dead or orphaned (means it will be killed once reconciled).

Comment: AFAIK, it's not easy to guarantee that two tasks are not running concurrently. Imagine a situation when a slave with your task is disconnected from the Mesos Master (due to a network partition). While you will get a `TASK_LOST` update and the Master ensures the task is killed once the connection is restored, your task will be running on the disconnected slave until then.

Comment: Got it, makes sense. Is it possible to write a custom executor that kills its task if it fails to communicate with master? And maybe the master and slave could agree about the timeouts so that TASK_LOST would actually guarantee the task was already killed by the slave?

Comment: You can write out-of-band health checks, but how will you solve the case when the machine is disconnected from the network for a while?

Answer (score 1):

You can assume that `TASK_LOST` really means your task is lost and there is nothing you can do but launch another instance.

Two things to keep in mind though:

1. Your framework may register with failover timeout which means if your framework cannot communicate with slave for any reason (network unstable, slave died, scheduler died etc.) then Mesos will kill tasks for this framework after they fail to recover within that timeout. You will get `TASK_LOST` status after the task is actually considered dead (e.g. when failover timeout expires).
2. When not using failover timeout tasks will be killed immediately when connectivity is lost for any reason.